# SQL: Adding data from one table to an already existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have an SQL Database that has one table with a lot of external ids (not pk or fk) missing.
I have selected these missing ids for each missing data row in an excel file. 
How can I insert these to the data where they belong to?

Comment: SImple java or c# application?

Comment: I'd use the python script, or export them to CSV file and import to database

Answer (score 0):

If you load the data from your Excel file into a new table, you can then use an UPDATE statement based on a join to update those rows in your original table.

How you load the data depends on whether you are using Microsoft SQL Server, mySQL, Oracle or anything else. If Microsoft and you have SQL Management Studio installed then SQL Server Import and Export Wizard will be a quick solution.

UPDATE statement based on a join would look like this:

```
update      tgt
set         tgt.externalID = src.externalID
from        originalTable tgt
inner join  myExternalFile src
on          tgt.ID = src.ID
```

originalTable being your table already in the database and myExternalFile being the table holding the data you have just loaded from the Excel file. ID is the field (probably primary key) that is common in both tables.

If you are using Oracle the syntax for UPDATE using a join is different but the above works in Microsoft and MySQL.

Comment: What is the question here?